# how can i edit a room reservation in laravel 8.the update on the controller does not work

Tags: laravel-8, updates, edit

**controller(update) :as you can see in the update i'm trying to edit the room reservation(time and date),but onlly one part work the if or the else!**

```
public function update(Request $request,  Roomreservation $roomreservation)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'date' => 'required',
            'time' => 'required',
        ]);
        $roomreservation = Roomreservation::where('date', request('date'))->where('time', request('time'))->where('code_room', request('code_room'));
        if ($roomreservation->exists()) {
            return back()->with('erreur', 'The chosen room is already reserved');
        }
        else {
           $roomreservation->update([
                "date" => $request->date,
               "time" => $request->time,
           ]);
            return back()->with('message_sent', 'room reservation edited successfully!');
        }

    }
```

**my form**

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.roomreservations.update', $roomreservation->id) }}">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('PUT') @method('PUT')
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <label for="date">Date</label>
                                            <input type="date" min="2022-01-01" max="2022-12-31" name="date" id="date" 
                                                   value="{{ old('date', $roomreservation->date) }}" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <label for="time">Time</label>
                                            <select name="time" id="time" 
                                                    value="{{ old('time',$roomreservation->time) }}" >
                                                <option>8H30-10H00</option>
                                                <option>10H00-11H30</option>
                                                <option>11H30-13H00</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <button>
                                                Edit
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

**button update on the index form**

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.roomreservations.edit', $roomreservation->id) }}" >Update</a>
```

**i think something is wrong on the update condition**

```
$roomreservation = Roomreservation::where('date', request('date'))->where('time', request('time'))->where('code_room', request('code_room'));
            if ($roomreservation->exists())
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're passing a wrong parameter
Change your update function to the below

```
public function update(Request $request,  $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'date' => 'required',
        'time' => 'required',
    ]);
    $roomreservation = Roomreservation::find($id);

    if ($roomreservation == null) {
        return back()->with('erreur', 'The chosen room does not exist');
    }

    if ($roomreservation->date == $request->date && $roomreservation->time == $request->time && $roomreservation->code_room == $request->code_room) {
        return back()->with('erreur', 'The chosen room is already reserved');
    }
    else {
       $roomreservation->update([
            "date" => $request->date,
           "time" => $request->time,
       ]);
        return back()->with('message_sent', 'room reservation edited successfully!');
    }

}
```

Comment: now the first part is working .but the condition does not work:                                           <this part>                                                                                                                            if ($roomreservation->date == $request->date && $roomreservation->time == $request->time) {
            return back()->with('erreur', 'The chosen room is already reserved');
        }

Comment: @malk I have edited the condition statement, Please check it now.

Comment: thank you so much for your help .but the first part                                                           if ($roomreservation->date == $request->date && $roomreservation->time == $request->time && $roomreservation->code_room==$request->code_room) still does not work